# How to use a different `default_env` per Capistrano role

Tags: ruby-on-rails, capistrano

In my deploy.rb, I have:

```
set :default_env, -> { {
  PATH: "some/path/to/stuff"
} }
```

I also have two servers:

```
server 'hostname1', roles: %{web app}, primary: true
server 'hostname2', roles: %{db}, no_release: true
```

For commands that run on hostname2, **I'd like to use a different `default_env`, is that possible?**

```
task :my_task do
  on roles :db do
    # do work
  end 
end
```

Comment: Hey @ardavis did you find a solution to that?

Comment: Unfortunately not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There isn't one way to use a different `default_env` directly, but you can rewrite its key-value pairs.

You should try this way:

```rb
task :my_task do
  on roles :db do
    with PATH: "/var/www/subdirectory" do
      # do work
    end 
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

you can create a rake to setup different path based on the environment and then run the rake with default environment as parameter 
task :setup, :roles => :db do
  run "rake developer:setup default_evironment=#{rails_env}"
  end